# How can I build a div that displays the .scrollTop value of the body?

Tags: javascript

On my webpage I've got the following div:

`<div style="position:fixed; z-index:100;"></div>`

I'm trying to write a script that will return the current .scrollTop value of the body within the above div (e.g., if I'm scrolled 100px down the body, I would like the div to simply read: "100"), but I'm having a lot of trouble grasping .scrollTop and have no clue where to even start. Any help?

Comment: are you useing jQuery in your code?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: ok, i'm assuming you have already got the answers?

Comment: I've got a couple that I'm working with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a timing loop to continuously display the value:

```
<div id="a">0</div>
```

JS:

```
var showScroll = setInterval(function() {
     document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = (document.body.scrollTop)                                 
},50)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery here. You can bind a listener to the scroll event and have it replace the content of your div with the result of `scrollTop()`, like this:

```
var div = $("div"); //Replace this selector with an ID for your div
$(document).scroll(function() {
    div.html($(window).scrollTop());
});
```